# Can't modal to next viewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I feel like I am just missing something simple here.  I am trying to modal to my next view controller.  I imported the next view controller in my first .m file first.  After I did that I wrote this code

```
CRHViewController *nextViewController = [[CRHViewController alloc]init]; 
        [self presentModalViewController:nextViewController animated:NO];
```

Also, I am working with storyboard and not nibs.

What happens when I run this is as soon as it goes to modal to the next viewcontroller it just goes black.

Am I missing something simple? Does anyone have an suggestions to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're not initialising it correctly. For testing purposes I would try to display CRHViewController as first root viewController from AppDelegate and find if it is initialising at all. Then check if it gets to its methods:

1. initWithNibName
2. loadView
3. awakeFromNib
4. viewDidLoad
5. viewWillAppear
6. viewDidAppear

In this order. Its 90% certain that one of them fails. Check if it gets to every method you have implemented correctly in this order.

Answer (score 0):

If your CRHViewController is in your storyboard, then you should be instantiating it with:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"yourStoryboardName" bundle:nil];
[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myIdentifier"];
```

You should give your view controller an identifier in IB to pass in as the identifier parameter in the above method.